# Convert GPS coordinates to coordinate plane

Tags: iphone, math, dictionary, gps, coordinate-systems

This is somewhat related to another question I asked: [Translate GPS coordinates to location on PDF Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870166/translate-gps-coordinates-to-location-on-pdf-map).  That got me to this point, now I'm stuck on the math.

Let's say I have a floor plan of a building, I've taken gps coordinate readings from each corner of the building.  Also assume that the floor plan is lined up with the latitude and longitude.

How do I convert a GPS coordinate to a X,Y position on this map?  I can't seem to get the math right.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let `delta_long` and `delta_lat` be the differences, in degrees, in the GPS coordinates of the building's corners.  Let `delta_x = 320` and `delta_y = 480` (feet, let's say).  Then:

`vertical_scale = delta_y/delta_lat`  with units feet/degree latitude

`horizontal_scale = delta_x/(cos(latitude)*delta_long)` with units feet/degree longitude.

The `cos(latitude)` factor compensates for the varying length of 1 degree of longitude
as one moves from the equator to the poles. We can assume for this application that
it won't change appreciably between the north and south ends of the building.

Then for any nearby (lat,long) point, subtract off the coordinates of the southwest
corner of the building, and apply the vertical and horizontal scales in the obvious
way to locate that point with respect to the building layout.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  I forgot to mention, the iPhone coordinate's plane is reversed, so that (0,0) is in the top left corner of the sample image.  How does this affect the calculations?

Comment: It should be mentioned that this is the "Equirectangular projection" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection

Comment: So Jim, you are saying that `x = ( lon_origin - lon ) * horizontal_scale` and `y = ( lat_origin - lat ) * vertical_scale`, where lat_origin,lon_origin are gps coords of the southwest corner. Right?

Comment: @Marco: I'd use  `(lon - lon_origin)` and `(lat - lat_origin)`  to make the signs come out right, but that's the idea, yes.

Comment: I'm little confused. (lon - lon_origin) is delta_long. isn't it? Can you kindly edit your answer in order to explicit formulas that brings to x and y?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is calculate the ECEF coordinates of the lat/long point:

[Latitude and Longitude, GPS Conversion](https://web.archive.org/web/20181018072749/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51832.html)

Comment: The building layout does not represent an earth-centered coordinate system, so this is quite different from what christo16 is looking for
(which is closer to a topocentric than a geocentric position).