# Converting GPS coordinates into 3D model

Tags: c#, xna, gps, heightmap

As the question says, I am looking to use GPS coordinates (say from Google maps) to build a 3D model (a road).

So it should work as follows:
You go to Google maps and select a route (this can be between 2 points or a circuit). You then get the lat long coordinates for this route.

Using this data, you then feed it into a program that generates a height map of the coordinates as obtained from Google maps.

I am trying to make a demo in C# (XNA) that you can quickly generate a course of your neighbourhood for a driving sim (as long as I get the main road sections right its ok, wont be able to add detailed characteristics of the road e.g. a ditch next to the road or small bumps in the actual road surface).

Does anyone have any ideas on where I would even start with a problem like this (tried Google already but the best I could find was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588653/convert-gps-coordinates-to-coordinate-plane))

Comment: If you somehow can obtain all the coordinates for this route in as much detail as possible, isn't it as simple as calculating the distance between each coordinate to get the positions of the road? If it's 10 metres from point A to point B in the Z-direction, draw 10 metres. http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html I don't know how much detail you can get from google maps; road bumps and such but perhaps calculating the route is a start.

Comment: You can also check out this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/ Example JSON: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false&avoid=highways&mode=bicycling which gives you all coordinates between two or more routes. So it's simply a request to google maps and then calculate the distance and create a route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPS coordinates (latitude, longitude, altitude) uses a **speherical** 3D modell. What you want is a transformation to a **cartesian** 3D Model.

For this case you can convert them into ECEF coordinates, this then are a x,y,z coordinates

For ECEF overview see [ECEF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF)

Answer (score 1):

A starting point could be to look at the Dotspatial libraries for .NET: http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/

I have used these libraries, but mainly to gather GPS coordinates from an external device. I haven't used these coordinates on a map for instance. The documentation is limited, but if you pry around you might be able to find some info.

Comment: Thanks Davio, Ill have a look at that for sure.